# Subsequences of subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A sequence $S = \{s_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of real numbers is a function from I (the set of positive integers) into $\mathbb{R}$ (the set of real numbers).

Definition above is given in Methods of Real Analysis by Goldberg

Say you have sequence S. You know nothing about it other than these things:
(1) It is a sequence
(2) It has subsequences

You also know those subsequences have subsequences of their own.

I am trying to prove that every subsequence of a subsequence of S is itself a subsequence of S. It seems risky to assume convergence or limit the approach to a specific set of numbers.

For example, I can say that $\{a_n\}$ is sequence in the natural numbers (every even natural number perhaps) and $\{b_n\}$ is a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ such that $b_i$ = $a_{\mathrm{2i}}$ for all integers i. Hence $\{b_n\}$ = (4, 8, 12, 16).

Obviously, $\{b_n\}$is also a subsequence of the natural numbers, but I have sacrificed generality.

Comment: It feels like you've missed something out of your description.  What does a sequence (or subsequence, or subsubsequence) that *doesn't* have a subsequence of its own look like?

Comment: What is a sequence and wuat os a subsequence? How is this defined?

Comment: the reason why $b_i$ can be viewed as subsequence of $a_i$ is because $b_i=a_{2i}$, and not because $b_i=2a_i$

Comment: What do you mean by you "have sacrificed generality"?

Comment: I think the logic behind your post is what I'm trying to avoid, @postmortes. I'm aware that every sequence in the real numbers has a monotone subsequence. Likely, many of them (perhaps all), have subsequence of their own. I might be missing a theorem somewhere, but I'm not seeing how your question helps me prove the question I have.

Comment: @miracle173, I'm not trying to prove this for a particular sequence. The question is meant to be general. For any sequence with subsubsequences in real analysis, what is the logic used to show the subsubsequences are subsequences.

Comment: "monotone" is new here, you haven't mentioned it previously.  How important is it?  The problem I have is this: take any sequence you like, say $(-1)^n$.  Drop the first two elements.  What is left is a subsequence, which is, naturally, a sequence itself.  In this case, it's identical to the parent sequence.  So you need to be clear what differentiates a sequence from a subsequence in order to have a question at all

Comment: check wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Subsequences

Comment: I'm referring to the Monotone Subsequence Theorem. My point with that comment was that any sequence of reals has some subsequence.

Comment: @BobMcdonald subsequences of sequences are sequences. So subsubsequences of sequences, which are subsecuences of subsequences, are again subsequences of sequences.

Comment: I'm not sure I got it right, but you want to take a sequence $(a_n)$, take from it a subsequence $(b_n)$, and from that subsequence $(b_n)$ take a subsequence $(c_n)$, and conclude that this subsubsequence $(c_n)$ of $(a_n)$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$?

Comment: @Ilovemath to whom are you talking?

Comment: @Bob Mcdonald, but I saw that you have already given a good answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Bbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers (say starting at $1$) and let $E$ be any non-empty set (for the typical case, suppose $E=\Bbb{R}$). Here are (the super formal) definitions:

1. A sequence in $E$ is by definition a function $a:\Bbb{N}\to E$.
2. A sequence $b:\Bbb{N}\to E$ is called a **subsequence** of the sequence $a:\Bbb{N}\to E$ if there exists a strictly increasing function $\theta:\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}$ such that $b=a\circ \theta$ (for example if $\theta(i)=2i$, then $b(i)=a(2i)$ so the $b$ is the "even subsequence" of $a$).

So, with this definition, suppose we have three sequences $a,b,c:\Bbb{N}\to E$
and that $b$ is a subsequence of $a$, and that $c$ is a subsequence of $b$. We wish to show that $c$ is a subsequence of $a$. This is immediate, because by hypothesis, there exist strictly increasing functions $\theta_1,\theta_2:\Bbb{N}\to \Bbb{N}$ such that $c=b\circ \theta_2$ and $b=a\circ \theta_1$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
c&=b\circ \theta_2=(a\circ \theta_1)\circ\theta_2=a\circ(\theta_1\circ \theta_2)
\end{align}
Note that $\theta_1\circ\theta_2$ is a composition of strictly increasing functions $\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}$, so is itself a strictly increasing function $\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}$. This shows $c$ is indeed a subsequence of $a$.

---

Of course, standard terminology/notation demands that we write $a_n$  for the $n^{th}$ term rather than $a(n)$, and that we denote the whole sequence as $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ or $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ rather than the single letter $a$ to denote the function $\Bbb{N}\to E$.